# Wordpress / CSS , сдвигается контент при добавлении фрейма

Tags: html, css, wordpress, веб-программирование

Сдвигается основной контент при добавлении фрейма.
Страница, где я добавил фрейм: https://israstar.com/st_tour/jerusalem-in-the-footsteps-of-jesus/
Страница без добавления: https://israstar.com/st_tour/israel/
Контент, который должен быть справа (видно на странице без добавления) сдвигается вниз после добавления фрейма. Отображение фрейма:

[image: ФРЕЙМ]

Контент, который сдвигается вниз:
[image: Контент]

Код фрейма:

```html
<div class="ben1">
<strong><span style="color: #FFFFFF">Pick Up, Prices and Languages Table<strong><span style="color: #FFFFFF"> 
<br>
<iframe src="https://www.beinharimtours.com/affiliates/schedule/?apiId=38&amp;affiliate_id=2361" width="100%" height="300px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<br>
<iframe src="https://www.beinharimtours.com/affiliates/pricestable/?apiId=38&amp;affiliate_id=2361" width="100%" height="300px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<br>
<iframe src="https://www.beinharimtours.com/affiliates/booking/?apiId=38&amp;affiliate_id=2361" width="100%" height="630px" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
if (e.data &amp;&amp; e.data.eventName == 'bookNowButtonClicked') {
// Open booking popup here!
}
}, false);
</script>
</div>
```

Буду благодарен за ответ, как исправить чтобы все было ровно.

Comment: А Вы смотрели в инспектор кода? На странице без фрейма вот тот блочек что должен быть сбоку лежит внутри `row`, а там где Вы добавили свой фрейм он завернут в два тега `strong`. Если его оттуда вынести, то все ок.

Comment: Ну и в том коде что Вы привели здесь, тоже есть два открывающих `strong`, не вижу ни одного закрывающего.

Comment: + 2 открывающих спана и ни одного закрывающего.